# How to disable security warning in firefox using selenide?

Tags: firefox, selenide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1srup.png)
I am getting this error while i run in firefox(version **42.0**). when i check it in chrome , it does not show up.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you look at the URLs in FireFox vs Chrome, do they differ? You get this warning because you as submitting a form using HTTP and not HTTPS, so perhaps the URLs are different.

Comment: Hello
No, URL In both  of them is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass through security warning using selenide by the following:

```
WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().switchTo().alert().accept();
```